# Tablelayout rows containing labels cutting off content

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayout

I have a form which collects users input through a number of richtextboxes. This is saved to the database. I have another form which displays this to the user using a TableLayoutPanel with a number of rows. Each row contains a label which displays the corresponding data.

The problem I am having is trying to display this data. The rows don't seem to expand to fit. I've tried the below to re-size the label so it pushes the row out but it doesn't seem to work

```
txtTest.Text = String.Format("{0}", loadRec.Content);
txtTest.Height = TextRenderer.MeasureText(txtTest.Text, txtTest.Font).Height;
```

The rows are set as AutoSize and the table as Auto Scroll to accommodate the content.
I've tried Docking the label and setting the Anchors Top, Bottom, Left, Right.

Am I missing something really basic? I've spent way too much time on this already.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you should just use a ListBox instead of putting labels in a TableLayoutPanel.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I added a report viewer with a report displaying all the information I wanted. Tried a few other ways but couldnt get the desired output. Thanks for the comments.